# Append values from csv file to a list and then sort

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple csv file with two columns. I wanted to add an additional name and score to the csv file, then sort the csv file by score.

I was trying to create a 2d list and add the new items, combine it with the items from the orignal csv file, sort the 2d list using lambda and then overwrite the csv file with the new sorted list. (I don't know if this is the most efficient method.)

It sorts values that are the same e.g. 3 digit numbers but doesn't seem to sort if I put in 4 digit numbers.

```
import csv


tmp = []
tmp2 = []

tmp.append([])
NameOfPlayer = input("Please enter name of player:\n")
PlayerScore = input("Please eneter score:\n")

tmp[0].append(NameOfPlayer)
tmp[0].append(PlayerScore)

print(tmp)
datafile = open('scores.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')


for line in datareader:
    tmp.append(line)

sort = sorted(tmp, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for line in sort:
    tmp2.append(line)
datafile1 = open('scores.csv', 'w')
x = 0
for row in tmp2:
    newRec = tmp2[x][0] + "," + tmp2[x][1] + "\n" 
    x = x + 1
    datafile1.write(newRec)
datafile1.close()
```

Comment: I don't see how this code would make any distinction between 3-digit numbers and 4-digit numbers. It will sort lexicographically, not numerically, though, since you never convert the data you read from the CSV file to numbers.

Comment: Is it possible its an error with replit?

Comment: Most likely not.

Comment: You might need to change your input from a string to an integer. For example, in the first for loop, you could try `tmp.append(list(map(float,line)))`

Comment: @BenGrossmann That would convert to a `float`, not to an integer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The same could work with `int`, of course. I wasn't sure whether the quantities here are integer valued

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes. I was just pointing out that you suggested to do one thing and then showed example code that does another thing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 ...It seems I was overdue for a cup of coffee

Comment: Thank you Ben and Mkreiger, column [0] is a string because its the player's name so it doesn't like that. How would i do it so it just column [1] being coverted into an integer

Comment: You can do the conversion to number with `key=lambda x: float(x[1])`. This leaves the actual values as strings. Also you can use join to make `datafile1.write('\n'.join(map(','.join, tmp2))`

Comment: Thanks yousefi that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the **pandas** module?
It makes a lot of flat file acrobatics pretty simple.
Here's the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html

For instance, you can import a csv like this:

```
import pandas as pd
player_df = pd.read_csv("../players_data.csv")
```

And in this case if you'd want to append new records all you'd have to do is append a dictionary to the dataframe object (made from the csv) with the column names (should be in the first row of the .csv file) as the keys and the new values as the dictionary values. Assuming that your column names are "Name" and "Score" :

```
player_name = input(" Please enter name of player:\n")
player_score = input("Please enter score:\n")

player_data = {
"Name":player_name,
"Score":player_score
}

player_df.append(player_data, ignore_index=True)
```

Sorting by a column (Score) is just as easy:

```
player_df.sort_values(by='Score', inplace=True)
```

And if you want to save the .csv to disk again:

```
player_df.to_csv("../players_data.csv")
```